# How to increment number of hits in database when a website link has received a click?

Tags: java, seo

I am developing a link exchange directory which displays different website links. I want to show number of hits a website link has received against each link. There is a table 'websitelink' in database in which one column is NumOfHits. Its initial value is '0' and it is also shown infront of each link.

Now i want that when any user click on any link the numOfHits automatically increment in database.
How to receive numOfHits and how can i increment the number of hits when any user click on a link?

I am developing the application in java using netbeans and mysql.

Comment: I don't know that how to get the url of link when a link is clicked. Do i have to use onclick() or anything else like this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
update websitehits set
numofhits = numofhits + 1
where url = ?
```

Executed by the web service code.

Comment: Thanks but please also tell me that how i'll get the value of url? the code of listing all the links is as follows:'<a href="<c:url value='${url.url}'/>">${url.title}</a>'. Now tell me how i'll get the value of url? is some hidden input is used?

Answer (score 0):

You need either an onclick event on the link that makes a call back to the server with the url that has been clicked or a redirector on your server that links get sent through.  Examples are below.

```
<a href="http://othersite.example.com/" onclick="pingMySite(this.href);return true;">
```

OR

```
<a href="http://mysite.example.com/clickthrough?url=http%3A//othersite.example.com">
```

Comment: I want that when link is clicked the url of link should go to the servlet. how the value of url will be capture from onclickk event and how it will be send to the servlet? Actually i don't know in detail about javascript.

Comment: If you don't know about javascript and AJAX, then the second option of  redirection would be a lot easier for you.  Write a clickthrough servlet that get the url param, increments its count, and issues a redirect to it.

Comment: Are you talking about the second code example that you have given? I have a servlet names Controller servlet. Should i use it? Please tell me in the second example what is this 'clickthrough?url=http%3A//othersite.example.com"' used for?